# gfortran not found; clang:error: linker command fialed wite exit code 1

Tags: c++, r, gcc, gfortran, rcpparmadillo

I recently install and uninstalled my R and Rstuido. Now, I am getting trouble to source cpp file. My main question is how to solve the error and how to change te compiler to gcc instead of clang.

## My errors are given:

```
using C++ compiler: ‘Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)’
using SDK: ‘’
clang++ -arch x86_64 -std=gnu++17 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include   -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"/Users/yuzi_mi/Desktop/~/RA-J-L/BSFP-1/C++" -I/opt/R/x86_64/include    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c likelihood.cpp -o likelihood.o
clang++ -arch x86_64 -std=gnu++17 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/opt/R/x86_64/lib -o sourceCpp_9.so likelihood.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin23/13 -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/bin/../libexec -lgfortran -lquadmath -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: library 'gfortran' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sourceCpp_9.so] Error 1
```

## The Session informations are also given:

```
R version 4.3.3 Patched (2024-02-29 r86148)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.0

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: America/Chicago
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.3           tools_4.3.3              RcppArmadillo_0.12.8.1.0
[4] Rcpp_1.0.12
```

Here is something I tried

```
which gfortran
/opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran
```

```
gfortran -v

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin23/13/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-apple-darwin23
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc --libdir=/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/current --disable-nls --enable-checking=release --with-gcc-major-version-only --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-13 --with-gmp=/opt/homebrew/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/opt/homebrew/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/opt/homebrew/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/opt/homebrew/opt/isl --with-zstd=/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 13.2.0' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues --with-system-zlib --build=aarch64-apple-darwin23 --with-sysroot=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.sdk
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 13.2.0 (Homebrew GCC 13.2.0)
```

So I updated makeconf to be:

```
FC = /opt/local/bin/gfortran -arch x86_64
FCFLAGS = -Wall -g -O2 $(LTO_FC)
FCLIBS_XTRA = 
FFLAGS = -Wall -g -O2 $(LTO_FC)
FLIBS = -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin23/13 -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/bin/../libexec -lgfortran -lquadmath
FPICFLAGS = -fPIC
FPIEFLAGS = -fPIE
F_VISIBILITY =
```

But I still get the error that gfortran not found.
Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Can you find `libgfortran.*` in any of the directories you have added with `-L`?

Comment: How did you come up with the use of the `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/bin/` directory for the -L option? Why would you expect libgfortran there? What is in the `lib` or `lib64` subdirectory?

Comment: libgfortran.* is needed, not the executable gfortran.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава `bin/../libexec` etc probably comes from the toolchain and not OP. It's not uncommon - but in this case it seems `libexec` is mentioned twice and `lib`/`lib64` not at all :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Makes sense, I was seeing a stray space there o my mobile phone. What seems suspicious to me are the directories  `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc` but then suddenly also `/opt/local/bin/gfortran` and `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc`/ and the prefix `/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc`. It seems very inconsistent. I would like to know from where the Gfortran installation actually comes.

Comment: @ VladimirFГероямслава Thanks for the comments. I installed gfortran through `brew install gcc`. I also tried `xcode-select --install` (I got a message that the command line tools are already installed). I did not try to uninstall gcc and reinstall gcc becase I got a warning that this may break some dependency.

Comment: @YMMMM Please clarify, is there any libgfortran in `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin23/13`? Is there any somewhere inside `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/libexec/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin23/13/lto-wrapper`? Is there any libgfortran somewhere else? What actually is in those mentioned directories? You are the only one who can see what is in the computer, so we depend on that information from you.

Comment: I did not find libgfortran in `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin23/13`, niether in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/libexec/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin23/13/`.  I found gfortran-13 in `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/13.2.0/bin/gfortran-13`. And I tired `which libgfortran` and nothing is returned.

Comment: And what actually is in those directories? BTW, you are looking for a file called libgfortran.dyld or similar. It is a library. Just gfortran is an executable that you do *not* need for linking.

Comment: I find identical files and folders in these two path. There are several Unix Executable File (e.g. cc1, cc1obj, cc1plus) and two folders called install-tools and plugin.  I could not find libgfortran anywhere in my directory. Does that mean when I did brew install gcc, gfortran was not installed?

Comment: If you can't find `libgfortran.*` then you don't have the necessary package installed. Are there any `*dev*` packages with similar names to those you have installed?